# What's a good way to convert the string "2.0" to a generic Fractional and "2" to a generic Num?

Tags: haskell

In GHCi, we can do

```
ghci> :t 2.0
2.0 :: Fractional t => t
```

So it's natural to ask, how does one convert the string `"2.0"` (parsed from an external data source) into a `Fractional t => t`?

Similarly, how to convert `"2"` into `Num t => t`?

I guess there are multiple ways to do this. Which is your favorite?
(As Haskellers, we like beautiful solutions.)

Comment: Beautiful would be to never have `"2.0"` as a _string_, in the first place... — but, [both of these functions are](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Numeric.html#v:readInt) [available in `base`, in the `Numeric` module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Numeric.html#v:readFloat).

Comment: @leftaroundabout Are you referring to databases that store 2.0 with an appropriate numeric type? (Plain text csv files don't have that, but sure, I agree that that ain't beautiful.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In GHCI:

```
λ> read "2.0" :: (Read a, Fractional a) => a
2.0
λ> read "2" :: (Read a, Num a) => a
2
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether it's beautiful or not. But, We can do as follows.

```
Prelude> (fromInteger . read) "2"
2
Prelude> :type it
it :: Num c => c
Prelude> (fromRational . (toRational :: Double -> Rational) . read) "2.0"
2.0
Prelude> :type it
it :: Fractional c => c
```